# single thick arrow bent 90 degrees instead of two double thick arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw such arrows in my tikz document -

[image]

and I have done it using the following code -

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex]
\usepgflibrary{shapes.arrows}
\node [single arrow, draw=none,fill=black,opacity=0.5, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=1.5cm,anchor=west,rotate=90] at (-3.25,-1) {}; 
\node [single arrow, draw=none,fill=black,opacity=0.5, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=1.6cm,anchor=west] at (-3.12,-0.845) {}; 

\node [single arrow, draw=none,fill=black,opacity=0.5, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=1.5cm,anchor=west,rotate=90] at (4.25,-1) {};
\node [single arrow, draw=none,fill=black,opacity=0.5, minimum width=0.8cm, minimum height=1.60cm,anchor=west,rotate=180] at (4.12,-0.845) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I find a gap between two arrows, especially when I use `scalebox`. I don't want to have this gap between the arrows, rather I want to make it feel like one single arrow. Could anyone tell me how to do it please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `arrow box` shape like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [arrow box, 
  arrow box shaft width=0.125cm, 
  inner sep=0.125cm/2, % should be half shaft width
  fill=gray, 
  arrow box arrows={north:.5cm, west:0.5cm}]
  {};

\node [arrow box, 
  arrow box shaft width=0.125cm, 
  inner sep=0.125cm/2, % should be half shaft width
  fill=gray, 
  arrow box arrows={north:.5cm, east:0.5cm}]
  at (1,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could place two path manually (not very elegant, but working, needs cvs version of tikz):

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\def\lwidth{3mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[garrow/.style={black!50!white, line width=\lwidth},
    garrowtip/.style={-{Triangle[length=5mm,width=8mm]}},]
    \draw[garrow] (.5*\lwidth,0) edge[garrowtip] (.5*\lwidth,2);
    \draw[garrow] (0,.5*\lwidth) edge[garrowtip] (2,.5*\lwidth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: By using the CVS version of TikZ.

Comment: @percusse thx, wasn't aware that I need the cvs version for the arrow tips